# How to change the path in terminal shell for github repository?

Tags: git, configuration

I am a first time learner and can't push up to GitHub.

The path is incorrect:
It is:  https://github/com/TedLaskaris/test-repo.git/
How do I change it to:  https://github.com/TedLaskaris/test-repo.git/

I don't know how the "`/`" got there.
And I don't know how to change it to a "`.`"

Answer (score 1):

You can change it with [`git remote set-url`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote):

```
git remote set-url origin https://TedLaskaris@github.com/TedLaskaris/test-repo
```

(I prefer adding the `TedLaskaris@` part, to avoid having to enter the username when pushing)

For the second error message (`Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind`), I would recommend a `git pull --rebase`, in order to rebase your local commit on top of the updated `upstream/master`.
See for example "[Failed to push some refs when pushing feature branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17906799/6309)".
(since you are the only one pushing to your GitHub repo for now, rebasing is ok)

[image: https://www.atlassian.com/pt/git/workflows/pageSections/00/contentFullWidth/0/tabs/00/pageSections/05/contentFullWidth/00/content_files/file1/document/git-workflow-svn-6.png]

See the section "[**Mary tries to publish her feature**](https://www.atlassian.com/pt/git/workflows#105Maryt1c+8092ff4)" of the Atlassian article "[**Centralized Workflow**](https://www.atlassian.com/pt/git/workflows#!workflow-centralized)".

Comment: Von thank you so much unfortunately I still can't git push up this simple .md file ... when I git push I get the results below and it tells me to git pull, which then gives me more unintelligible "hints"

Comment: Theadore:test-repo tedlaskaris$ git push
To https://TedLaskaris@github.com/TedLaskaris/test-repo
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://TedLaskaris@github.com/TedLaskaris/test-repo'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.